# Laravel populate foreign key data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships, lumen, lumen-5.2

Hi I am new to Laravel and trying to make a RESTFul api with Laravel Lumen
I have installed the laravel and Lumen and I have the version as

`Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.2.6) (Laravel Components 5.2.*)`

Now I have in addition I have installed the https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence for mapping the DB column names and I have done so far as

**Contacts model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence; // base trait
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable; // extension trait

class Contacts extends Model {
    use Eloquence, Mappable;
    protected $table = 'contacts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idcontacts';
    protected $visible = ['firstname', 'lastname','idorganization'];
    protected $maps = [
        'firstname'=> 'firstName',
        'lastname' => 'lastName'
    ];

    public function organization() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Organization','idorganization');
    }
}
```

**Organizagion Model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Organization extends Model {

    protected $table = 'organization';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idorganization';
    protected $visible = ['organization_name', 'website','website','phone','num_employes','industry'];

    public function contacts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Contacts', 'idorganization');
    }
}
```

And the controller for the Contacts looks like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Contacts;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function getAll() {
        $contacts = Contacts::all();
        return response()->json($contacts);
    }
}
```

But the response does not populate the `idorganization` with the model columns from organization.

I in addition tried as
`$contacts = Persona::with('organization')->all();`

But it returns error as

`Call to undefined method Sofa\Eloquence\Query\Builder::all()`

If I remove the `Sofa\Eloquence` in Contacts model and the traits it still does not work.

Please let me know I am missing something obvious

Without the relation I get the response as

```
[
 {
    "firstname":"Abhik",
    "lastname":"Chakraborty",
    "idorganization":"1"
 },
 {
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Martin"
    "idorganization":"1"
 }
]
```

Expected result would be

```
[
     {
        "firstname":"Abhik",
        "lastname":"Chakraborty",
        "organization":{
          "organization_name": "foo"
          "website": "bar"
          ..................
        }
     },
     {
        "firstname":"John",
        "lastname":"Martin"
        "organization":{
          "organization_name": "foo"
          "website": "bar"
          ...............
        }
     }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your response does not populate the `idorganization` field when you call `all()` is that relationships are lazy loaded by default meaning that relationship data will be loaded when you actually access them.

To accomplish what you want, you need to use `get()` method instead of `all()` when you are using `with()` method which is named as [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Replace this:

```
Persona::with('organization')->all();
```

With:

```
Persona::with('organization')->get();
```

Comment: @Baurak you are correct ! The eager loading is the solution. I in-fact removed the `hasOne` to `belongsTo` on Contacts model something as `public function organization() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Organization','idorganization');
    }`
And visible property I set as `protected $visible = ['firstname', 'lastname','organization'];` and I got exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.